# Why am I getting RunTime warning while computing cost function for logistic regression?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, logistic-regression, loss-function

```
<ipython-input-20-5561a7703323>:8: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  cost=(-y[i]*np.log(g_i) - (1-y[i])*np.log(1-g_i))
<ipython-input-20-5561a7703323>:8: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  cost=(-y[i]*np.log(g_i) - (1-y[i])*np.log(1-g_i))
nan
```

This the output I am getting on calling the following function in Jupyter Notebook .

```
def linear(x,Q):
    z=np.dot(x,Q)
    return z

def sigmoid(z):
    g_x=1/(1+np.exp(-z))
    
    return g_x

def costf(x,y,Q):
    m = y.shape[0]
    cost_sum = 0
    for i in range(m):
        z_i=linear(x[i],Q)
        g_i=sigmoid(z_i)

        cost=(-y[i]*np.log(g_i) - (1-y[i])*np.log(1-g_i))

        cost_sum+=cost

    total_cost=cost_sum/m

    return total_cost

cost=costf(x,y_pred,Q)
cost
```

I expected a value for the cost function. I don't think anything is wrong with the mathematical formula.

[Formulas Used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnX7f.png)

Comment: It's saying that `g_i` is zero.  Perhaps you should an `assert` to check that.

Comment: @TimRoberts g_i is 1 or near 1 for all iterations.0.9999999999999991
0.9999999999093123
0.9999999999999973
1.0
1.0
0.9999999999999805
The g_i for the first few iterations.

Comment: If `g_i` is 1, then `1-g_i` is zero.

Comment: That formula can't be right.  You're at the very last digit of precision for a float, so `1-g_i` is basically producing garbage.  You don't get meaningful results when you subtract two floats that are very very close to each other.

Comment: @TimRoberts  I added the link to the image for the formula that is being used for computing the cost function. The result for sigmoid function is supposed to come out between 0 and 1, but 1 is coming out as result as well.

Comment: I tried Z-Score Normalisation on my dataset and the cost function is now being computed properly. I don't understand the need to use it although, my dataset is already scaled between 20-100, I don't think it is vast enough for there to be a need to perform normalisation. I performed it on a whim and it worked.